# Does Google Chrome experience more broken links than other browsers?

Tags: google-chrome, links

Is it just me or does Google Chrome fail to link more often than other browsers?

I was previously using Firefox and constantly reloading the page wasn't an issue.

Comment: provide an example of what "works" in firefox and what doesnt't in chrome. (i suspect you are stumbling upon the fact that chrome does not try to prefix 'www.' to the url if the url is not working and lots of domain-names do not work without the 'www.' [because their admins do not give a rats ass]).

Comment: Do you have any Chrome extensions installed? Do you have a virus scanner that is interfering with your browsing?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question about web browser functionality.

Answer (score 1):

I can safely say no, awhile back I thought this was happening to my personal site on Chrome but after I did a few brute force tests, it was actually my webhost so it's not Chrome. 
I am assuming you're using a stable Chrome and not a development version because those could have some problems I might not know about.